# sense of RESTful requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, rest

I have a ruby-on-rails application and I'm now wondering why RoR uses Restful Requests:
eg. if you want delete an ressource it's a best practice to do it with such an HTTP Request:

```
DELETE /entry/13
```

you can also do it with with such an normal request:
`GET /entry/delete/13` or `GET /entry/13/delete`

now my question:
when i make a link to such an restful delete operation with the link_to helper

```
link_to :controller =>:delete, :id => id, :method => :delete
```

it results in some cryptic javascript:

```
<a href="/entry/13" onclick="var f = document.createElement('form'); f.style.display = 'none'; this.parentNode.appendChild(f); f.method = 'POST'; f.action = this.href;var m = document.createElement('input'); m.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); m.setAttribute('name', '_method'); m.setAttribute('value', 'delete'); f.appendChild(m);var s = document.createElement('input'); s.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); s.setAttribute('name', 'authenticity_token'); s.setAttribute('value', 'GIep/wk5+6EMX23qY4TAP7joKy/G3f5uvMI6d6n9vlA='); f.appendChild(s);f.submit();return false;">Delete</a>
```

So whats the idea behind it? 
In my opinion you just exclude non-javascript users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All versions of Rails < 3 use very obtrusive javascript (and the result is pretty ugly, as you've demonstrated).

The doc [suggests](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M002142) the method will fall-back to using GET if javascript is disabled:

> :method => symbol of HTTP verb - This
>   modifier will dynamically create an
>   HTML form and immediately submit the
>   form for processing using the HTTP
>   verb specified. Useful for having
>   links perform a POST operation in
>   dangerous actions like deleting a
>   record (which search bots can follow
>   while spidering your site). Supported
>   verbs are :post, :delete and :put.
>   Note that if the user has JavaScript
>   disabled, the request will fall back
>   to using GET. If you are relying on
>   the POST behavior, you should check
>   for it in your controller‘s action by
>   using the request object‘s methods for
>   post?, delete? or put?.

Either way, I would suggest you create the "destroy" links like so:

```
# when you have an "entry" object
link_to "Destroy", entry, :method => :delete

# when you only have an "entry" object's id
link_to "Destroy", entry_path(:id => id), :method => :delete
```